# Not able to modify Cordova WebView

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, webview

I'm developing Cordova application with EmberJs. There I require to local ajax calls, i.e, ajax call to file:/// url. Cordova doesn't allow that. So I found that I need to modify Cordova WebView settings. For that, I tried this code:

```
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;
import org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebView;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;

public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity
{
    SystemWebView webView = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        webView  = (SystemWebView) appView.getView();
        WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        }
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
    }
}
```

But I'm always getting following error:

```
Runtime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.scb.prototype/com.scb.prototype.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.View org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.getView()' on a null object reference
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.View org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.getView()' on a null object reference
                                                         at com.scb.prototype.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:37)
                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

appView is returning null. Any solution for this?
If anyone can suggest how to allow ajax from file:/// url in Cordova, that will also resolve my issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how a `file:///` could be a ajax server?

Comment: I can't put it in server because of the offline capability of my application :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting NullPointerException because super.init() is not called and your appView is not initialized.

SystemWebView webView = null;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();
    // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
    webView  = (SystemWebView) appView.getEngine().getView();
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    }
    loadUrl(launchUrl);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :) I have very less idea about Android. Thanks again for your answer.

Comment: I had to add another settings too to make it work, so for me it was:

            ```settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
            settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);```